# How to pass size param to carrierwave helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Im trying to make 1 global function to display carrier wave images in different sizes. the problem is passing the size var in method call to the carrierwave helper like below:

def get_avatar(id, size)

```
@profile = User.find(id).profile rescue nil
  image_tag @profile.photos.first.file_url(:img_120x145)
rescue
  image_tag ("/assets/avatars/img_#{size}.png")
```

end

I tried all kinds of things but are unable to pass the   **size** var to the @profile.photos.first_url(size here).

How should one approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres what worked for me recently.

`<% image_tag @profile.photos.first.url(size) %>`